# What data structure is typically used to implement a frame table?

Tags: operating-system, paging

I have to implement a frame table for an operating systems project, to keep track of which frames in physical memory (not pages of virtual memory) are in use or free. One of the big things is deciding on a data structure to use for the frame table. In your experience, how are frame tables typically implemented, with regards to what data structure they use? In my case, the entries have to hold pointers to the frames in physical memory. Would you recommend using an array, list, hash table, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Both Windows and Linux use an array of structures where each element of the array describes a page frame of the physical address space. So if there are a total of 128 page frames, then the array would contain 128 structures.

On Windows this array is called the PFN database. Each structure describes the state of the frame (whether allocated or free) and usually includes one or more physical addresses of those page table entries that map to it. To make finding free frames more efficient than just linearly scanning the array, each element contains a pointer to the next element of the same state. So basically there is a linked list of free frames.

On Linux, the array is called [mem_map](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand005.html) and there is one such array for each NUMA node in the system.